# Error in Apache Ignite : Can't restore memory - critical part of WAL archive is missing

Tags: ignite

I was trying to run my application that uses an Apache `ignite` cache in a local Windows machine and got the below error:

```
ERROR [exchange-worker-#42%ignite-instance-0%] [] - Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=class o.a.i.failure.StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler, failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=class o.a.i.i.pagemem.wal.StorageException: Restore wal pointer = null, while status.endPtr = FileWALPointer [idx=0, fileOff=3746370, len=53]. Can't restore memory - critical part of WAL archive is missing.]]
class org.apache.ignite.internal.pagemem.wal.StorageException: Restore wal pointer = null, while status.endPtr = FileWALPointer [idx=0, fileOff=3746370, len=53]. Can't restore memory - critical part of WAL archive is missing.
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.readCheckpointAndRestoreMemory(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:759)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onClusterStateChangeRequest(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:894)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:641)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2419)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2299)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea what might have gone wrong?

My `dataStorageConfiguration` is :

```
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="walMode" value="LOG_ONLY"/>
        <property name="walCompactionEnabled" value="true" />
    </bean>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you lose your WAL? If you don't care about any preexisting data at all, consider removing your Ignite work dir (typically `ignite/work` or `%TMP%/ignite/work`).

Comment: I am just trying to set it up. I dont have any data. The Error is :  ERROR [exchange-worker-#42%ignite-instance-0%] [] - JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=class o.a.i.i.pagemem.wal.StorageException: Restore wal pointer = null, while status.endPtr = FileWALPointer [idx=0, fileOff=3746370, len=53]. Can't restore memory - critical part of WAL archive is missing.]]

Comment: This error means that you actually do have data from some previous run.

Comment: Thanks it got resolved with removing the ignite/work directory. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Today i see that the directory is not created and hence i dont see to solve the problem anyway!! Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it is there somewhere. You can specify path to this directory by setting `igniteWorkDir` parameter, and this is a recommended thing to do.

Comment: if I delete that file, I will lose my data. it is not a good solution.
and I am getting this error frequently. Every time, I can not delete the work file. deleting is not a good solution. There should be a reason that causes this problem and a solution

Comment: You need to find out why that happens. Normally it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the solution:

Delete the following directory 
Windows : C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\ignite
Linux : find the directory with heirarchy ignit/work and delete it.

Comment: if I delete that file, I will lose my data. it is not a good solution. and I am getting this error frequently. Every time, I can not delete the work file. deleting is not a good solution. There should be a reason that causes this problem and a solution